# RMarkdown automatically adding unwanted whitespace

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, pandoc

Trying to figure out why this code adds an entire page of white space to my document when rendering to pdf (windows10, tex live, everything up-to-date)

This version skips the entire first page after the header in the pdf:

````
---
title: "quiz_1_takehome"
author: "PSYC243"
date: "July 9, 2017"
output: 
    pdf_document:
        number_sections: true
---

# Load the `mtcars` data and save it as `my_data`, e.g., `my_data <- mtcars`. 
```{r echo = FALSE}
my_data <- mtcars
```
## We don't need to worry about where this data is (e.g., we don't need to examine the working directory with `getwd()` or `setwd()`) because `R` automatically loads it when it starts.  


# Print the length of `my_data` with `length()`. 
## What happened? Is this information useful for examining dataframes? Why or why not (Respond in a comment)?
````

This version does not add the whitespace. I only deleted a bit of extra parenthetical text about `getwd()`

````
---
title: "quiz_1_takehome"
author: "PSYC243"
date: "July 9, 2017"
output: 
    pdf_document:
        number_sections: true
---

# Load the `mtcars` data and save it as `my_data`, e.g., `my_data <- mtcars`. 
```{r echo = FALSE}
my_data <- mtcars
```
## We don't need to worry about where this data is (e.g.,  with `getwd()` or `setwd()`) because `R` automatically loads it when it starts.  


# Print the length of `my_data` with `length()`. 
## What happened? Is this information useful for examining dataframes? Why or why not (Respond in a comment)?
## Now print the result of using `dim()` with your dataframe. Why is this more useful?  

# The previous functions are great for finding the most basic info about the dataframe but there is so much more we'd want to know. Use the functions we have used in class to explore the data. 
## How many variables are there? What are their types? The functions you use should provide all this information so print it to the console (i.e., do not manually count and type this information).
````

So the whitespace issue seems to be tied to the length of that section, this makes no sense to me and it doesn't appear to happen anywhere else in my document. Why does RMarkdown appear to arbitrarily add whitespace in this example?

Here is one more example where I am experiencing this problem:

````
---
title: "hw5"
author: "PSYC243"
date: "July 18, 2017"
output: 
    pdf_document:
        number_sections: true
---


# Load the housing price data, `landdata-states.csv`, and name it `housing` (on bb).


## You'll probably want to change the variable names with `tolower()`. 
```{r, eval = FALSE}
colnames(housing) <- tolower(colnames(housing))
```  

## Examine the `home.value` data by `date`. Create a visualization that shows the states with the most volatile (i.e., changing) state housing markets. Make sure this graph prints---don't just create it and assign it.


## Print the acronyms of five states you identify as the most volatile (you do *not* need to do this programmatically, a simple `print( c('state1', 'state2', ... )` statement will work.)


### There are several ways you could do this. You could visually inspect the data with a well-designed graph (or graphs). You could use one of our descriptive statistics (i.e., what would give us a measure of variability in the data?). You could also manually look at the data (though that would be the most work-intensive approach)


# One problem with looking at housing value by state is that costs in each state are dramtically different---meaning value in one state might not be on the same scale as value in another. 


## Use a `for()` loop to standardize the `home.value` variable by state. This is identical to the process we used in class except that we are using different variables. Step by step instructions are directly below.


### Create a vector named `std_home_value` and a vector named `state`.
### Use a `for()` loop to iterate through the state and standardize the values *from each state only* using `scale`.
### On each iteration of the loop, save the values and state labels into your vectors `std_home_value`, and `state` with `c()`.
### Finally, assign your `std_home_value` vector to a column in the `housing` data frame.

## Now examine the new variable you created (i.e., the same plots/code should work, you only need to change variable names). Did this standardization change you opinion about volatility in the states? Explain what changed and revise your answer.
````

[image: rmarkdown whitespace issue]

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue, all seems perfectly normal. Are all packages up to date?

Comment: Ok. Sorry, no. Will update and re-test

Comment: yes all packages up to date and the problem remains, also added another instance of the problem.

Comment: I've isolated a cause of this problem to `number_sections: true`. When I remove my markdown pound signs the behavior goes away, not a solution but a clue.